# does the default private setting kick in after inheriting a class public

Tags: c++

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {

    int _classMember1;
    int _classMember2;
  };
```

I know that the default access for a class is private, but I do not know what happens when I inherit publicly from a BaseClass. Does that public access also apply to _classMember1 or _classMember2 or they continue to stay private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They continue to be private since by default they are private. Public inheritance will not make them public. Otherwise, it violates encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

The private member of derived class remain as private irrespective of whether it inherits from base class as public.